# Why 鍵{かぎ}を開{あ}ける instead of 鍵で開ける

Tags: grammar, particles, verbs

So I am a beginner when it comes to Japanese and today I stumbled upon the phrase "鍵を開ける".
As I understand, one of the usages of the particle で is, how something or where something is done.
i.e: 日本語で話{はな}す or 家で働{はたら}く

While the particle を is used to define the object of the action.
So I assumed "鍵を開ける" would mean "to open the key". But it doesn't.

- Why is that?
- Is 開ける just an exception when it comes to particles?
- Are particles generally used differently depending on the verb?
- Am I misunderstanding something or is this just another use of the particle を?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[鍵 also means "lock"](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%8D%B5), not just "key".  Yes, it will take your English-speaking brain some time to come to terms with it.

Comment: I feel a bit more explanation would help because 窓が鍵を開ける would literally mean "the window opens the lock". So there's more going on here than just 鍵 having the meaning of 'lock'. This phrase doesn't seem right to me but I don't have enough confidence to provide an answer myself.

Comment: @user3856370 sorry, was a mistake on my part, I edited it out.

Comment: @BennySchärer Ah, good. I feel happy again :-)

Comment: @user3856370, I've never encountered that construction myself, and [I can't find anything for that specific phrase in Google.](https://www.google.com/search?q="窓が鍵を開ける")

Comment: @BennySchärer, any chance the 窓が鍵を開ける phrase might have been slightly different?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi You must have missed the OP's comment above. I think all the confusion has been cleared up now :)

Comment: @user3856370, I also missed that they'd updated their main post, which removes the 窓が portion.  Humph for stale browser tabs.  :)  Cheers!

Comment: @BennySchärer The following may not be something a language learner should know, but: there is a word that properly refers to locks, which is じょう (錠).  I would consider using かぎ to refer to a lock is an instance of metonymy.  Not that one often hears the sentence 錠をあける.

Comment: Would it be natural to say 鍵で鍵を開ける to mean "Open the lock with the key"?